Home Network Speed
I only have very basic networking knowledge and need help with the following.
Currently, all my home devices are connected to ports running at 1GbE (broadband, router, switch, Mac, NAS). However, I plan to progressively upgrade my equipment to 10GbE eventually. Doing a 'big bang' approach is too costly and is out of the question. So, my plan for now is as follows:

Retain the current 1Gbps internet broadband
Retain the current router (A) with 1Gbps WAN port
Buy the QNAP QSW-2104-2T switch (B) (which has 2x10GbE ports and 4x2.5GbE ports, all on RJ45)
Add a 10GbE adapter to my Mac and connect it to one of the 2x10GbE ports on the switch (B)
Add a 10GbE card to my NAS and connect it to the other 10GbE port on the switch (B)
Use one of the 2.5GbE ports on the switch (B) as an uplink port to my router (A)

Questions:

Is this a viable solution for my home network for now?
Will my Mac and NAS be able to communicate at 10Gbps (or close to it)? If not, what will be the possible network speed that they will be communication at, 1Gbps? I know that my internet access is still 1Gbps.

Appreciate your advice and recommendations. Thanks!

They will of course communicate at the higher speeds within your network to devices that support the higher speeds. Your modem will NOT be one of those devices

your plan seems reasonable.

Thanks for your quick reply. Glad to hear that this is a viable plan. Also glad to know that my Mac will be able to access my nas at the highest possible speed and not be ‘hamstrung’ by the slowest speed device connected to the switch.

Now do keep in mind, at 10Gb/s, your bottleneck will likely become your storage speed, so don't expect you will get anywhere near that with single real-world operations.

Good point. Thanks for the reminder, Frank!
